# A quick way to create building

Tags: modeling, add-on

[Reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MU_L_HvvULM)

With the reference [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj2gJLt4J0U)

Is there any addon or quick way to make building from the base shape. Im making a city model with the texture or material. With the reference video a good shape building i can create with texture or material. With the setting it should suggest the floor i need, etc. With OSM (Open street Map) it just create the basic square or basic shape not the building shape with windows. Any addon or a quick way making the building.

[image]

[New Addon Building generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GixKhqrdANs)

**SHAPES THAT NOT WORKING ON IT** https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZS2Y0YlA3dUtKa28

Normal Shape its creating a regular rectangular building

http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=119314

Comment: There is [Scene City](http://cgchan.com/) - not free.

Comment: @sambler does it creates creates window and texture. There are no video tutorial how it works

Comment: I haven't actually used it so don't know exact details. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDioWz45PiQ)

Comment: array modifier comes to my mind.

Comment: @sambler Thanks for the video. Actually it creates the build which are inbuild not with the base shape. The OSM make the shape as per the map. And with the mesh or the flat shape selected i want to make that build not the preloaded or default model. In the reference video kludgecity you can see with the circle or different base mesh it build the build. Hope u get what i mean. plz watch the video of the addon what i need but giving some error. Link is given in the video and addon in the description

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve this as you would want in blender.
There is no current add-on that creates procedural buildings (geometry) from shapes. All you can do is import the OSM with building geometry and then procedurally/manually texture the buildings.

Please see this tutorial on how to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4ySFm4ey9U

Be advised OSM does not have height data outside of North America.

Comment: have u seen above new addon generator link and the video given but its giving error

Comment: The BCGA addon hasnt been worked on since 2015, its probably not compatible with current Blender versions. This isnt a new addon, id wager this is an abandoned project nobody ever finished.

Comment: @AdamTM19 i have used it in 2.79 and created the towers also watch this http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=119525